# How to send email alert to admin after delete a python setup file using linux?

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x

I want to send an email alert using the linux os when user delete python setup file. i made a screenshot program using python, unfortunately if user uninstall python setup file.I want to send an email to the admin. if you know the processing steps kindly share with me or please give any suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to *not* allow the user delete the script. Put the script in one of the non-core `bin` directories, e.g. into `/usr/local/bin` as `root` and regular user will not be able to remove it.